# How can I pass a parameter with submit button on form

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to create the from that can change product data in mySQL made by PHP.
and I have the key column that auto increment and specify each product.
When i click to edit product link .it will pass the key values that i get from each product
and link to   editPage.php

```
$Key = $data['Key']; 
<a href=\"editPage.php?Key=".$Key."\">edit</a>
```

in editPage.php i get the key values from previous page and i want pass thisvalues to next page with submit form button.I attach Key values in action link.

```
<?$Key = $_GET["Key"];?>
<form id="form2" name="form1" method="post" action="editWeb.php?Key=".$Key." \">
```

It don't work, Can I pass Key values with another ways. Tell me if you want more information 
Thanks!!:))

Comment: yeah you may use hidden field!

Comment: What about `Key=" onsubmit="alert('xss');` ?

Comment: Do you have a submit button for your form?

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="<?php ?>">

Comment: **You are vulnerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)**. Don't inject external data into HTML documents raw.

Comment: Your method is "post", you shouldn't mix up GET and POST.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to echo the value.

```
<form id="form2" name="form1" method="post" action="editWeb.php?Key=<? echo $Key ?>"/>
```

You could also use a hidden input:

```
<form id="form2" name="form1" method="post" action="editWeb.php"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Key" value="<? echo $Key ?>" />
```

Comment: This does not seem to work when I load a json datalist with ajax. I have a list of 20 forms (foreach loop with ajax), yet each one submits the same hidden input... Any idea on why that is?

Answer (score 5):

you need to create a `hidden` input field and place that value in it. and then submit the form

```
<input type="hidden" id="Key" name="Key" value="<?=$Key ?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form id="" name="form" method="get" action="page.php"/>
 <name="" input type="hidden" value="">
 <input type="submit" value="">
 </form>
```

GET->show hidden value on required page url.generally we use GET to pass values, it depend upon your requirement.