# Update an ID after getting it with GET

Tags: php, sql, database, post, get

PHP part:

```
if (!empty($_GET['ID_personne'])) {
    $id = checkInput($_GET['ID_personne']);
}
// ....................

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $CIN = checkInput($_POST['CIN']);
    // ................
    $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE personnes  
                                set 
                                ID_personne =:cin, 
                                Nom = :nom, 
                                Prenom = :prenom, 
                                Telephone = :telephone, 
                                Mail = :mail,
                                Categorie=:categorie,
                                Type=:type
                                WHERE ID_personne = :id");

    $statement->bindValue(':cin',$CIN);
    $statement->bindValue(':nom',$nom);
    $statement->bindValue(':prenom',$prenom);
    $statement->bindValue(':telephone',$telephone);
    $statement->bindValue(':categorie',$categorie);
    $statement->bindValue(':mail',$mail);
    $statement->bindValue(':type',$type);
    $statement->bindValue(':id',$id);

    $statement->execute();
    header("Location: personnes.php");
}
```

HTML part:

```
<!-- ............. -->
<form class="form" action="update_personnes.php" role="form" 
    method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="CIN">CIN:</label>
        <input maxlength="8" minlength="8" type="text" class="form- 
  control" id="CIN" name="CIN" placeholder="CIN" value="<?php echo $CIN;?>">
        <!-- ............... -->
```

NB: The points mean that there is code, but it is useless for resolving my error.
I wanna update my `id` after filling the form, then clicking on modify, it doesn't work even for the other columns BUT:

if I change this line:

```
 $statement->bindValue(':id',$id);
```

with

```
 $statement->bindValue(':id',$CIN);
```

the other columns change whereas the ID didn't change.

Comment: Well your code says you use GET and POST at the same time.  Which one is it?

Comment: i use the GET to get the id that i want to change it and POST to take the new id

Comment: But in the HTML I don't see where you are passing the $_GET, your action variable only has a filename

Comment: from an other file with this code 
  '                   
  echo '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="update_personnes.php?ID_personne='.$personne['ID_personne'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Modifier</a>';'

Comment: I'm confused, you can't send 2 files doing two different sets of actions to the same program at once.  You might have to restate how this works.

Comment: if i didn't do that i can't get the id to update it

Comment: the first file it's only display the database and the second one a form to update each column and other file to delete it

Comment: If you want to simultaneously sent $_GET and $_POST at the same time, then use `action="update_personnes.php?ID_personne={$personne['ID_personne']}"`  then you will have the original `id` AND you will have the new _POSTed_ value.  Are you seeing all the expected data when you call `var_export($_POST)` and `var_export($_GET)`?  I can't think of any application where I would want to allow a user to modify the unique id of a row.

Comment: i can't add this "{   }" . i got an error.
i have to change the id because in my application the id it's the number of the idendity card

Comment: To use a php variable, you will need to be "inside php".  Here's the shortened syntax to echo a php variable into html: `<form class="form" action="update_personnes.php?ID_personne=<?=(int)$personne['ID_personne']?>" role="form" 
    method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass a parameter with submit button on form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492699/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-with-submit-button-on-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i change the form in the HTML part and it works:

```
             <form class="form" action="<?php echo 'update_personnes.php?ID_personne='.$id ?>" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score -2):

Form another file with this code

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="update_personnes.php?ID_personne='.$personne['ID_personne'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Modifier</a>';
```